# HAProxy don't balancing requests between nodes of Galera cluster

Tags: haproxy, cluster, high-availability, keepalived, galera

I stuck with the problem with balancing requests from app server to Galera cluster nodes.

The strukture of HA is

**`node1 10.62.10.35 (HAProxy + Keepalived) Master`**

**`node1 10.62.10.36 (HAProxy + Keepalived) Backup`**

**`node1 10.62.10.37 (HAProxy + Keepalived) Backup`**

Configuration of the Master Keepalived node1

**`global_defs {
  router_id PSQL1
}
vrrp_script haproxy {
  script "killall -0 haproxy"
  interval 2
  weight 2
}
vrrp_instance 50 {
  virtual_router_id 50
  advert_int 1
  priority 101
  state MASTER
  interface ens160
  virtual_ipaddress {
   10.62.10.254/22  dev ens160
  }
  track_script {
    haproxy
  }
}`**

Configuration of the Backup Keepalived node2

**`global_defs {
  router_id PSQL2
}
vrrp_script haproxy {
  script "killall -0 haproxy"
  interval 2
  weight 2
}
vrrp_instance 50 {
  virtual_router_id 50
  advert_int 1
  priority 3
  state BACKUP
  interface ens160
  virtual_ipaddress {
   10.62.10.254/22  dev ens160
  }
  track_script {
    haproxy
  }
}`**

Configuration of the Backup Keepalived node3 is the similar with the node2 except priority and router_id.

Configuration of the HAProxy is similar on each node

**`
frontend galera

```
    listen 10.62.10.254:3306
    mode tcp
    default_backend galera
```

frontend web

```
    bind *:8080
    mode http
    default_backend web
```

backend galera

```
    balance roundrobin
    option tcpka
    option mysql-check user haproxy_check
    server node1 10.62.10.35:3306 check weight 1
    server node2 10.62.10.36:3306 check weight 1
    server node3 10.62.10.37:3306 check weight 1
```

backend web

```
     mode http
     stats enable
     stats uri /
     stats realm Strictly\ Private
     stats auth Admin:admin
     stats auth Another_User:passwd
```

Keepalived works. If Master node is down (or keepalived/haproxy is stoped) then next backup node use 10.62.10.254 address. But when Master is alive and I stop only MYSQL on it HAproxy don't send requests to other nodes. When I stop Master keepalived, the Backup node also use only it local MYSQL server for requests.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for your replies and have a nice day.

Comment: I am wondering about the "backend - frontend" configuration for haproxy and the tcp keep alive... I do use only

listen mysql-cluster
    bind 192.168.10.55:3306
    mode tcp
    option mysql-check user haproxy_check
    balance roundrobin
    server percona-1 192.168.10.241:3306 check
    server percona-2 192.168.10.242:3306 check
    server percona-3 192.168.10.243:3306 check

Comment: When I use this kind of configuration I recieve "haproxy.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer."

Comment: haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -c
Configuration file is valid

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. If you start haproxy and MYSQL on one server you need to change port 3306 to 3307 in frontend.

**` frontend galera

```
bind 10.62.10.254:3307
mode tcp
default_backend galera
```